# While using https, When exactly data is encrypted?

Tags: encryption, https, ws-security

I was going through couple of forums to know difference between WS security and HTTPS, found a blog post:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbertocci/2005/04/25/end-to-end-security-or-why-you-shouldnt-drive-your-motorcycle-naked/

But I could't quite understand the below line from blog:

***You still have to leave home and reach the tunnel entrance, and once outside the tunnel probably you'll have to get off and walk somewhere... and that goes for HTTPS***

My understanding of HTTPS is that, browser takes care of handshaking with server and it keeps certificate and public key, though, not so sure if browser stores public key. So, when exactly data is encrypted using this public key? or what is the tunnel entrance here, do that tunnel entrance(whatever it is) also keeps public key?

Comment: That line you don’t understand talks about what happens after your encrypted data has reached the web server that you were communicating with via HTTPS - if that web server then sends the data for example to a MySQL database over an insecure connection, then an attacker could get the un-encrypted data there.

Comment: Yes, I understood that point, but isn't that should be the case for WS security too. So, just curious what this tunnel entrance in the blog.